# How add scrollTop option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm very newbie, how i can add to my code scrollTop  margin +100px ?
On page have some margin from top but i can't find him. And i can't understand where is typing margin-top in javascript file.

```
/*************
* = Parallax *
*************/
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    //Cache some variables
    var links = $('.nav').find('li');
    slide = $('.slide');
    button = $('.button');
    mywindow = $(window);
    htmlbody = $('html,body');

    //Create a function that will be passed a slide number and then will scroll to that slide using jquerys animate. The Jquery
    //easing plugin is also used, so we passed in the easing method of 'easeInOutQuint' which is available throught the plugin.
    function goToByScroll(dataslide) {
        var offset_top = ( dataslide == 1 ) ? '0px' : $('.slide[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').offset().top;

        htmlbody.stop(false, false).animate({
            scrollTop: offset_top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutQuart');


    }

    //When the user clicks on the navigation links, get the data-slide attribute value of the link and pass that variable to the goToByScroll function
    links.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
        goToByScroll(dataslide);
        $(".nav-collapse").collapse('hide');
    });

    //When the user clicks on the navigation links, get the data-slide attribute value of the link and pass that variable to the goToByScroll function
    $('.navigation-slide').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
        goToByScroll(dataslide);
        $(".nav-collapse").collapse('hide');
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to explain more on what are you expecting

Comment: I wan't to do that. http://ifelselab.com/test/dnd2/index2.html here my site. on top of page WE DO BUSINESS IN THE FORM OF ART. this image not in slide div. when i push to the button WHO WE ARE it must go under nav but it's not happen

Answer (score 0):

put this inside your click event for the "scroll to top" button/link/whatever..

```
$("body").scrollTop( 100);
```

Comment: how? i didn't understand

Comment: sorry i dont mean its simple, i mean you are very close.

Comment: i don't know how i can put all site to fiddle :)

Comment: not all site - just what you need, a mockup of stripped down html markup, some id's.. recreate the same problem your having.

Comment: i can give to link : ifelselab.com/test/dnd2/index2.html

Comment: I dont get it, when I run $("body").scrollTop(0); on that site, it brings me to the top.. sorry, can you explain exactly what you want to scroll to, and the control "who we are" you want that clicked to scroll to a certain part of the page?

Comment: I'm try to tell my problem with best way so :  http://www.donotdisturb.ch/new/  in this site if you will look. when you click to WHO WE ARE div shift to a little more to top and  WE DO BUSINESS IN THE FORM OF ART. this image going to under navigation. I wanna do same thing here ifelselab.com/test/dnd2/index2.html

Comment: OK.. I think I know what you mean @user3348410 .. your code in first website has `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:document.body.scrollTop = 134"><img src="http://www.donotdisturb.ch/new/theme/donotdisturb/images/menu_1.png" class="menu_1" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.donotdisturb.ch/new/theme/donotdisturb/images/menu_1_hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.donotdisturb.ch/new/theme/donotdisturb/images/menu_1.png'"></a>`

Change `javascript:document.body.scrollTop = 134` to `javascript:document.body.scrollTop = 0`

This is why it dissapear behind nav

Comment: Where i will write this ? javascript:document.body.scrollTop = 0   - in this site. ifelselab.com/test/dnd2/index2.html .. I'm working on this site

Comment: in your website where you have `href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:document.body.scrollTop = 134"`